# Magento 2: How to get current admin user detail?

Tags: magento2, admin-user

How to get the current admin user detail in back-end ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you need to add this to the constructor of your class

```
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, 
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    ....
}
```

Then create this method

```
public function getCurrentUser()
{
    return $this->authSession->getUser();
}
```

this will give you the current logged in admin.
You can later get the details like `$user->getUsername()` or `$user->getEmail()`.

Comment: Notice: After adding the codes, we need run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`,  otherwise it would appear "__Session none given__" error.

Comment: perfect answer with explanation!!! +1 :)

Comment: @Marius  I have added login as customer form backend. But I want admin details on product view page which admin login to the customer.

Comment: you cannot access admin session from frontend.

Comment: is there any method to know current user duration ?

Answer (score 9):

**How to get current admin user detail?**

inject backend session in your controller

```
public function __construct(
....
\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, 
  ....
 ) {
  ....
   $this->authSession = $authSession;
   ....
```

}

and use this to get user name or email

```
 $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
$this->authSession->getUser()->getEmail();
```

Comment: Not necessary to inject in your controller though.

Answer (score 4):

Your Controller already extends `\Magento\Backend\App\Action` so it already has the authorization object. No additional injections are needed.
To get the user simply use this function:

```
    /** @var \Magento\User\Model\User $user*/
    $user = $this->_auth->getUser();
```

Other answers are suggesting duplicate injections, which are not needed.