# Magento 2 passing more argument in Model

Tags: magento2, model, session, user

How can i add more argument \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
into \Magento\Store\Model\Website ?

I tried to get current user like following link:
[Magento 2: How to get current admin user detail?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105773/magento-2-how-to-get-current-admin-user-detail)

and it gave me error log:

Recoverable Error: Argument 14 passed to Magento\Store\Model\Website::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session, array given, called in D:\tait_magento\trunk\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\Website\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in D:\tait_magento\trunk\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Website.php on line 199.

Block dashboard throws exception and cannot be rendered.

And i have search and do everything from clearing /var/* folders or 
config di.xml but i can't have any results.

Please help me , the beginner with Magento 2.

This is my code:

```
    namespace Magento\Store\Model;

     class Website extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel implements
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface,
        \Magento\Store\Api\Data\WebsiteInterface
    {

    ....

         protected $_authSession;
         public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
                \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
                \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
                \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
                \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data $configDataResource,
                \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $coreConfig,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory $storeListFactory,
                \Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory $storeGroupFactory,
                \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
                \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
                \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        //        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
                array $data = []
            ) {
                parent::__construct(
                    $context,
                    $registry,
                    $extensionFactory,
                    $customAttributeFactory,
                    $resource,
                    $resourceCollection,
                    $data
                );
                $this->_configDataResource = $configDataResource;
                $this->_coreConfig = $coreConfig;
                $this->storeListFactory = $storeListFactory;
                $this->_storeGroupFactory = $storeGroupFactory;
                $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
                $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
                $this->_currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;

                //$authSession = new Session();
               // $this->_authSession = $authSession;
            }

            protected function _construct()
            {
                $this->_init('Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website');
            }

            public function getCurrentUser()
            {
                return $this->_authSession->getUser();
            }
......
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code of your constructor

Answer (score 1):

Required parameters must be before optional.

```
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
            \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data $configDataResource,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $coreConfig,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory $storeListFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory $storeGroupFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
            \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, // <-- your dependensies
            \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
            array $data = []
        )
```