# Magento 2 : Only show products that is uploaded by specific admin user

Tags: magento2, admin-user

I have created an admin user and i only want to display those products that is uploaded by him in backend but here all the products is displaying which other users have added instead of his products.
[image]

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: you can do it same thing using extension here is the link  - https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html

Comment: i cant buy or use any extension, how about custom code or what if i override the product module and make a condition here for displaying product..
but yes first i have to keep track of users who add products

Comment: Thats too broad to answer. In short I can suggest you can create a product attribute and save the user who created in it. Then you can override the product grid and in collection you can filter the current user and show him the products that are created by him only.

Comment: thanks but please can u help me with code coz i m just a beginner in magento 2

Comment: @userpk u there?

Answer (score 4):

I think its too long to explain all things in answer, but I can give you starting point so you can start from something,

- Create a new product attribute with `admin_user_id` in assigned to all your product attribute set and perform `reindex`.
- Create a new `observer` for the `catalog_product_save_before` event. You can find the similar answer here [Get product object after save](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/get-product-from-save-event-observer-magento-2/93986#93986)

  *Note: above link answer is for `catalog_product_save_after` but you can easily change the event with `catalog_product_save_before`*
- On save event you need to find current admin user id,which you can easily find from admin session. here is the answer [How to get admin user detail ?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105773/magento-2-how-to-get-current-admin-user-detail)
- After getting the admin user id save id to product attribute which we have created in first step. like

  `$product->setData('admin_user_id',1)` // this is example, you can replace with dynamic
- So on every product save you can find the admin user id, which is useful to differentiate the product between admin user.
- So after saving the product now its turn to hide the product for current user, which you can easily do by writing the `after` `plugin` for the `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider`

In this class `Magento` prepare the `product` `collection` for `product` grid. In this class you can find `getData` method. so this is your location filter the products with current admin user id.

To create a plugin File: `app/code/YOURVENDOR/YOURMODULE/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
        <plugin name="YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME" type="YOURVENDOR\YOURMODULENAME\Plugin\ProductDataProvider" />
    </type>
```

Here is the location,

```
    public function aftergetData(\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject
)
        {
            if (!$subject->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
                $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('admin_user_id','1'); //replace with dynamic admin user from session
                $subject->getCollection()->load();
            }
            .......................
        }
```

that's it to filter the product collection based on admin user.

Comment: my observer is not working its not saving attribute

Comment: `<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsavebefore implements ObserverInterface
{   
 protected $authSession;

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer,
     \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession)
    {
     $this->authSession = $authSession;
     $current_admin_id = $this->authSession->getUser()->getId(); 
          
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); 
        $_product->setData('admin_user_id', $current_admin_id);
  $_product->save();
    }   
}

`

Comment: this is my observer code

Comment: hellow you there?

Comment: my observer is not working also products are not displaying according to admin user id, i passed the static id there

Comment: In the answer I gave you idea, how you can achieve it , and If attribute is not saving then it belongs to another question, not this one :) @JayKapoor

Comment: okay please suggest how to filter products coz products are not displaying in admin panel accoring to attribute

Comment: Please see my last step, I already used last step in my previous projects and It was working fine :) , If plugin is not working (May be because of private, protected modifier)then try to override the class @JayKapoor

Comment: i tried everything but got nothing,..:(

Comment: Ok, please ask a new question with your codepool which you have tried so someone can help you @JayKapoor

Comment: i asked already please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191941/magento-2-get-products-in-admin-panel-using-plugin

Comment: and you got the answer :) @JayKapoor

Comment: Glad that it helps you @AmitSingh :)