# Magento 2: Get Products in admin panel Using Plugin

Tags: magento2, product-collection

i am using a plugin to filter products on admin panel by product attribute, but got no results.
here is my plugin code.

```
<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Plugin;

class ProductDataProvider
{
      public function aftergetData(\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject
)
        {
            if (!$subject->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
                echo 'jhsdg';
                $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('admin_user_id', array('eq' => '2')); //replace with dynamic admin user from session
                $subject->getCollection()->load();
                echo 'sghd';
            }
        }
}
```

and my etc/di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/
config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
        <plugin name="productdata" type="Learning\HelloPage\Plugin\ProductDataProvider" />
    </type>

</config>
```

what am i doing wrong? please suggest any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change method name aftergetData to afterGetData

**[Update]**

I think around plugin is best for you. Try following way using around plugin:

```
class ProductDataProvider
{
    public function aroundGetData(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        if (!$subject->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('admin_user_id', array('eq' => '2'));
            $subject->getCollection()->load();
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Try after plugin following way:

```
class ProductDataProvider
{
    public function afterGetData(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if (!$subject->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('admin_user_id', array('eq' => '2'));
            $subject->getCollection()->load();
        }

        $items = $subject->getCollection()->toArray();

        return [
            'totalRecords' => $subject->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items),
        ];
    }
}
```

***Don't use any echo/print inside this function. Try error log  or magento log for testing your plugin works or not.***

For example:

```
class ProductDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * ProductDataProvider constructor.
     *
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetData(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if (!$subject->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('admin_user_id', array('eq' => '2'));
            $subject->getCollection()->load();
        }
        $this->logger->info('TEST');
        $items = $subject->getCollection()->toArray();

        return [
            'totalRecords' => $subject->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items),
        ];
    }
}
```

Magento log file location: Magento Root /var/log/system.log

Clear cache.

Comment: hello sir, still i got nothing it keeps loading, but got no results

Comment: @Sohel It should  be aftergetData, as original method name is getData

Comment: @JayKapoor check updated answer.

Comment: @KeyurShah yes, that's why first character should be uppercase. Not aftergetData, should be afterGetData.

Comment: Yes, I am wrong, :) +1  from me @SohelRana