# Get userid of the admin logged in magento 2 helper

Tags: magento2, helper

Trying to get admin user id in Magento 2 helper,
in new at magento 2 any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This answer tells you how to pull the admin user details https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105773/magento-2-how-to-get-current-admin-user-detail

Answer (score 1):

Below is a helper with a dependency and you can see within one of its function how the backend user id is read

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\BackendScreen\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class AdminUserReaderHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
     */
    private $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }

    public function doSomethingWithMyAdminUserId()
    {
        ...
        if ($this->authSession->getUser() != null) {

            $adminUserId = $this->authSession->getUser()->getId();
        }
        
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: gettings : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUser() on null

Comment: thanks for your comment, it was a poor answer of mine, apologies